# Company name with the definite article

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

I have learned that names can be without an article. This is from Wikipedia:

> The Volkswagen Golf Mk7 (also known as the Golf VII[4]) is a compact
>   car

I would wrote this sentence with the zero article before Volkswagen. Is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would definitely not be okay if you omitted the definite article there. The quote from the Wikipedia page that you posted is not about the company Volkswagen. It's about a specific line of cars that they produce. And that line of cars is called *the Volkswagen Golf Mk7*. You can even get rid of *Volkswagen* from the model's name completely and shorten it to just *the Golf Mk7*. *Volkswagen* is only there to remind you about the name of the carmaker that manufactures this particular model of cars. There are many Golf Mk7 cars on the road, but as a model there is only one Golf Mk7 car. That's why, when we think of it as a particular model of car, we refer to it as *the Golf Mk7* with the definite article *the*.